# Why gcloud APIs are not as mature as gcloud cli?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

To list instances in a project

using CLI, we can list all the instances

```
gcloud computes instances list --project=<PROJECT-NAME>
```

using API, we can list instances per zone

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones/{zone}/instances
```

Can not we list all the instances using API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why gcloud APIs are not as mature as gcloud cli?

Google Cloud APIs are the foundation for `gcloud` CLI. I think you are confusing ease of use versus the raw interface. The API is a low level interface, and you do not really want the API providing "intelligence" on your behalf. Otherwise you cannot add new features or fix issues. The APIs should provide support for one well defined feature (a building block). The higher level software (gcloud) combines these features for presentation to the user.

When you access a zone, you are connecting to a data center. Therefore you will need to connect to each data center to access resources within the data center. For the most parts Google Zones are designed to be independant which helps with fault tolerance, availability, etc.

> using CLI, we can list all the instances
>
> gcloud compute instances list --project=PROJECT-NAME

This command, at a lower level, connects to each zone and retrieve the instance list. If you are using the API you will need to implement the logic yourself to connect to each zone and combine the results.

> using API, we can list instances per zone
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones/{zone}/instances
>
> Can not we list all the instances using API?

Yes, execute the API for each zone that you want to list instances for.

One item that you might have noticed. For some operations `gcloud` seems to do a lot of work and takes a while. For example listing all the compute instances in your project. I only have instances in one zone, so my API calls are very fast. In comparison `gcloud` must talk to all 55 Google zones to see what instances are in each zone. This makes the command slower in comparision to a command that only scans one zone.

In summary `gcloud` gives you ease of use, the API gives you raw power.

Comment: To add to this excellent answer: Here's the implementation of "instances list" in gcloud: [lister.py](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/2cc7b066a0621fe5d78ac9e69157de56a142e126/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/lister.py#L1056)
Per [LICENSE](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE) this code is distributed under Apache 2.0 so it may be possible to reuse it.

Comment: FYI, we can get kubernetes cluster list using - (Location "-" matches all zones and all regions.)
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/list

Comment: @k_vishwanath - Using `-` as a wildcard for the `PROJECT_ID` will infer the project from the account for most Google services. It does NOT mean all zones and regions for all APIs. Kubernetes is an exception. An account is service account's email address or unique ID used as credentials for the API call.